# Adobe Audition CS6 vs Syntrillium Cool Edit Pro 2.1 - editing wave

Tags: wave-editor

In Cool Edit Pro when a waveform is in maximum zoom level, it is possible to drag an audio sample vertically, or "Editing Sample Directly" by left clicking on an audio sample. How can I achieve the same in Audition ?

```
below : `Before drag (Cool Edit Pro)`
```

[image]

```
below : `After drag (Cool Edit Pro)`
```

[image]

```
below : `After left click on audio sample (Cool Edit Pro)`
```

[image]

```
below : `Can not drag (Audition CS6)`
```

[image]